# Siemens Panel Main Circuit Breaker Teardown

Tags: electrical

Ready for use:

[image]

What do you usually put in the screw nut so it can't loosen? I'm afraid all purpose general glue (alongside breaker in picture) may not stop it. If I put epoxy. It may be unremovable and can't screw it if needed in the future. Would a single mighty bond glue compound stop it (but this is supposed to be put between two materials). Any other idea? It's 1/8 in size and couldn't find any tiny locknut for it.

---

After teardown of the Westinghouse Breaker and handling it for a day at office during break removing the parts and putting them back again and again. It gave me courage to finally initiate teardown of the Siemens Load Center main circuit breaker (especially when no one can offer any clue what could be wrong with it and no teardown of it anywhere in the net).

I spent more than an hour in the evening removing the 4 mini-bolts manually so in case the defective is not mechanical or serious, I could still use it (the casing is not glued and there are only the 4 mini pins holding all of them together). So it's not technically a teardown but repair. I found out the problem. First youtube video of the internal parts and illustrations:

https://youtu.be/oQHDxviWRI4

[image]

It's just a typical circuit breaker internal components. Nothing unique. The source of the problem why you need to push it a bit more for the latching to be made is due to housing dimension tolerance. Compared to other breakers where the latching is made 75%. In the Siemens. It is 90% before the spring hatches it to make full contact. So slight housing misalignment need you to push it a bit more (and it is only in one of the breaker (remember it is two pole so has 2 separate unit). No problems with the bi-metallic strips or catch mechanism.

I assembled it back and will put it in service since nothing wrong with it. I checked dozen times the mechanical parts and orientation is same as original (with many photos taken in different stages of the teardown. My question is. What do you call this tiny pin-bolt? I can replace it with 4 thin long screws locking the breaker in place (by gluing the 4 nuts so they won't loosen or even epoxy it, isn't it?)  What did you do?

[image]

old message:

I just made teardown of a Westinghouse breaker and became so familiar with all the mechanisms I can take all things apart and assemble the inside.

[image]

[image]

Using the Westinghouse breaker teardown as sample. I couldn't extrapolate what is wrong with the Siemens.

I couldn't return the item. It costs $45. And a new one cost $85 shipped. So I need to know if what could possibly be wrong with the Siemens. Doesn't it use a standard latching mechanism? Any illustration of what mechanism it could be using?

Is this really defective?

In this even newer video.

https://youtu.be/tCqGNRzIMO0

I can consistently make it stay latched by pushing it after it is in the on position. Listen to the "click" after I turned it on (in first and second attempt, increase the volume of your speaker so you can obviously hear the click). In third attempt, I didn't push it so it returned. At 4th try I pushed it with a click and it stayed latched. Can't you consider it as tolerance? What mechanism inside the breaker is exactly involved, any idea?

earlier update.

I found out you need to slightly push the lever in so it can stay in on position. See this youtube video:

https://youtu.be/fTo2acI93XM

In the first and second attempt. I didn't push the lever so it returns to OFF position. In the third attempt. I need to push it gently down so it can be in On position. Is this normal, or is the subpanel breaker slightly defective? I have handled many other breakers and it doesn't have this behavior.

original post.

I bought a new subpanel, and the main breaker is already defective (brand Siemens). It can't be switched open (even isolated on piece of paper like in the picture). It returned to close position immediately. Usually what are the parts inside that get broken easily even without any use? Anyone has tear down such to see what is defective inside?

[image: 1]

Comment: **Back to the store it goes**.   Is that not a viable solution for you?  I would be reluctant to tear it down out of idle curiosity, as it's a pricey breaker.  They make $5 breakers that work the same way, buy one of those new and tear it down. Put it on youtube.   Also nobody's perfect but Siemens is a highly respected brand and probably has quite a long warranty on it.

Comment: Tearing down to an eye toward repair is out of the question. The cases on these things are glued and/or riveted together and are never meant to be repaired. Faulty == Return and Replace.

Comment: Harper, when your subpanel is just besides your main panel. Do you think it's better to just use lugs so no hassle when the subpanel main breaker gets defective. One can just depend on the main panel main breaker, right?

Comment: Although this is Very rare, take it back and get a replacement. I have had a very few failures with this, brand cutthler hammer and square D but have seen problems on occasions with my favorite brand.

Comment: Amazon doesn't allow return or replacement of one part only. And Siemens USA wont allow exchange by shipping it. They want me to return and exchange it with a physical US Siemens distributor (which I can't do since I live in the Philippines).  And local Siemens won't replace it because they said it was bought in USA. Therefore I can't use it anymore. Or maybe someone can help me return it to a US Siemens distributor? What are the steps or process for exchange usually?

Comment: I am just curious.  In the Phillipines, are fused main disconnects popular rather than main disconnects breaker OCPD?  Between availability, warranty issues, and counterfeits, maybe it's something to consider, especially if the service has enough room that you expect the main to seldom or never trip.

Comment: 99.99% (or almost all) uses breakers. and over 90% uses the GE brand breakers with locally built main panels. My main panel is locally made. I could have put the Siemens GFCI in it but the listed Siemens bus bar is a bit thicker.

Answer (score 2):

### Send the breaker back (as a warranty return), get some main lugs instead

This breaker is clearly NFG, and thus needs to be sent back under Siemens' warranty (it's a 1-year warranty, but that should do the trick for an infant mortal like this one).  While you're at it, what you want for a subpanel sitting right next to the main isn't a main breaker, but a set of *main lugs* instead -- the correct part for your panel will be a Siemens ECMLK125 kit.

This is because the busbars on such a panel are an extension of the feeder, so they are protected by the feeder breaker as the *feeder tap rules* aren't in play here, and the upstream and downstream panels are in the same building, so the downstream panel does not need to provide a master shutoff switch for power to its circuits.

Comment: Ok. I got the Siemens ECMLK125 kit. There are only 6 breakers in the subpanel with 30A rating each. Since it's Main Lugs, I can use the 90 degree table. Can I just get an AWG 4 to feed them? AWG 2 is just too big and only required if you are using the 100A main breaker.

Comment: See edited posts. I can't return the item. I need it to have a local disconnect at the subpanel. Even after teardown with an ordinary Westinghouse breaker. I still couldn't extrapolate what is the wrong with the Siemens. Maybe you have an idea and can share of a Siemens main breaker teardown? Thanks.